# How do I select all elements containing x?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Say I have a list like the following:

```
list={a+x,a+b+c,b+x^2,1+x,a+2+x,(d-x^2)^(1/2),b c d};
```

I would like to select all the elements of the list that contain x. That would be in this case:

```
list={a+x,b+b+x^2,1+x,a+2+x,(1-x^2)^(1/2)};
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Something like `Select[!FreeQ[#,x]&][list]`

Comment: Marvelous! Pleas write this down as an answer!! Need to look up FreeQ[]...

Comment: Done. I'm pretty sure, this is a duplicate of some question, though.

Comment: BTW, to those voting to close: it would be helpful to close as a duplicate, rather than other reasons, even though the question is trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the operator form of `Select`:

```
Select[!FreeQ[#,x]&][list]
```

Comment: Just to make it more interesting... what if I would want it to select any expression containing any element from a list {x,y,...}?

Comment: @MirkoAveta replace `x` with `Alternatives[x,y,...]`

Comment: Of course it follows that you could use `Cases[list, q_ /; ! FreeQ[x][q]]`, but can the matching be done without `Condition`?

Comment: @Alan you got me thinking whether there exists a pattern which stands for arbitrary nesting of some expression